# to live on land/on the ground?

Tags: idiomatic-language

In Russia, we can say that we live 'on land' if we have our own detached house with a square of ground.

Is there an expression like this in English, or is it strange to say that

you live

> on the ground
>
> on land

?

Comment: _On the ground_ means 'not up in the air' and _on land_ means 'not at sea'! I can't think of a brief phrase that means 'living in a detached house'.

Comment: Wow! @KateBunting thank you! That's really interesting!

Comment: Yeah, you definitely can't say "I live on the ground/land", because the alternative is that you live in the sky like a cloud, or in the sea like a fish!  Also oddly enough, if you say "I live **off** the land" it means that you eat only what you hunt and gather by yourself.

Comment: @stangdon thank you for the clarifications. I should say, "I live in a house". :D

Comment: In Canada, a [freehold property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freehold_(law)) is one where the owner owns the land outright, along with any structures on it. Not all English-speaking countries use this term though.

Comment: @CanadianYankee thank you for the information, but I am not sure it is relevant to my question. :)